# Instruments failing to launch from command line

Tags: command-line, launch, xcode-instruments

I have been trying to run Instruments from the command line.
But it fails with the following error:

```
2012-02-08 14:48:16.104 instruments[94502:60f] -[NSAlert alertWithError:] called 
    with nil NSError. A generic error message will be displayed, 
    but the user deserves better. 

Wed Feb  8 14:48:16 c1dev-dm23409.overstock.com instruments[94502] 
    <Error>: kCGErrorInvalidConnection: CGSGetCurrentCursorLocation: Invalid connection 

Wed Feb  8 14:48:16 c1dev-dm23409.overstock.com instruments[94502] 
    <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as 
    they are logged. 

2012-02-08 14:48:16.137 instruments[94502:60f] Recording cancelled : At least 
    one target failed to launch; aborting run
```

Can some tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the errors `Invalid connection` and the following `Set a breakpoint...` are what Instruments responds with when it has any kind of problem.

What's really important is the last line: `Recording cancelled : At least one target failed to launch`.

In my experience, this either means that your program was unable to load (provisioning profile, nonexistent build, etc) or that you didn't specify it correctly on the command line. Here's how I specify `instruments`:

```
$ instruments -t /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate 
    /path/to/my/AppName.app -e UIARESULTSPATH . -e UIASCRIPT testscript.js
```